# What is the equivalent way to achieve "ActiveDocument.Variables" in Outlook?

Tags: c#, plugins, outlook, outlook-addin, global

In my Word plugin, I've used "Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Varibles" to store/retrieve values. Is there any way to acomplish the same, in Outlook? Or is there any other way to store values from Outlook?

Comment: Did try accomplishing same in Outlook plugin yet? What are the issues you are facing and please share the code as well to better explain the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [StorageItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.storageitem) class which represents a message object in MAPI that is always saved as a hidden item in the parent folder and stores private data for Outlook solutions. A `StorageItem` object is stored at the folder level, allowing it to roam with the account and be available online or offline. You can read more about this solution in the [Storing Data for Solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/solution-storage/storing-data-for-solutions) article.

There are other possible ways of storing your data:

- [UserProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties) which contains `UserProperty` objects that represent the custom properties of an Outlook item. Use the `Add` method to create a new `UserProperty` for an item and add it to the `UserProperties` object. The `Add` method allows you to specify a name and type for the new property. When you create a new property, it can also be added as a custom field to the folder that contains the item (using the same name as the property) by setting the `AddToFolderFields` parameter to `True` when calling the `Add` method. That field can then be used as a column in folder views. Read more about that in the [How To: Add a custom property to the UserProperties collection of an Outlook e-mail item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/19/how-to-add-a-custom-property-to-the-userproperties-collection-of-an-e-mail-item-in-outlook/) article.
- Application-specific external files and DBs. See [What is the best way to store some data in VSTO addin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803924/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-some-data-in-vsto-addin/54201871). This is a common way of storing data externally for all kinds of applications.